# What is the cause of Tensorflow memory increase?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, keras

The development environment is Docker + Anaconda3.

There were approximately 500,000 image data and training sessions.

The sample source is "https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images?See hl=ko".

The model.fit function continues to increase memory.

What's the reason?

- The python3 process also increases.

```
import os
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import random
import math
import time
import linecache

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

FILENAME = 'mnist'
USE_GPU = False

WIDTH = 128
HEIGHT = 128
EPOCHES = 20
BATCH_SIZE = 256
DENSE = 10

if USE_GPU:
    print('- device GPU')
    os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
else:
    print('- device CPU')
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"

    tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
    
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import pathlib
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep
import psutil


class_names = ''

def get_label(file_path):
    # Convert the path to a list of path components
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
    # The second to last is the class-directory
    one_hot = parts[-2] == class_names
    # Integer encode the label
    return tf.argmax(one_hot)

def process_path(file_path):
    label = get_label(file_path)
    # Load the raw data from the file as a string
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = decode_img(img)
    return img, label

def decode_img(img):
    # Convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
    img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    # Resize the image to the desired size
    return tf.image.resize(img, [HEIGHT, WIDTH])

def configure_for_performance(ds):
    ds = ds.cache()
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
    ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    return ds


fileDir = pathlib.Path(r'./data/train')
image_count = len(list(fileDir.glob('*/*.jpg')))

list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(fileDir/'*/*.jpg'), shuffle=False)
list_ds = list_ds.shuffle(image_count, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)

for f in list_ds.take(5):
    print(f.numpy())
    
class_names = np.array(sorted([item.name for item in fileDir.glob('*') if item.name != ".DS_Store"]))
train_dict = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(np.unique(class_names))}

validation_size = int(image_count * 0.2)
train_data = list_ds.skip(validation_size)
validation_data = list_ds.take(validation_size)

print(tf.data.experimental.cardinality(train_data).numpy())
print(tf.data.experimental.cardinality(validation_data).numpy())

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
train_data = train_data.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
validation_data = validation_data.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

for image, label in train_data.take(1):
    print("Image shape: ", image.numpy().shape)
    print("Label: ", label.numpy())

train_data = configure_for_performance(train_data)
validation_data = configure_for_performance(validation_data)


image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(train_data))

    
start_total = time.time()

num_classes = 10
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
])


model.compile(
  optimizer='adam',
  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
  metrics=['accuracy'])

start = time.time()

model.fit(train_data, validation_data=validation_data, epochs=3) #Here...

end = time.time()

model.save(FILENAME, save_format="tf")

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(FILENAME)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,
                                    tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
tflite_model = converter.convert()

open(FILENAME + '.tflite', 'wb').write(tflite_model)

with open('labels.txt', 'w') as file:
    for key in train_dict:
        file.write(str(train_dict[key]))
        file.write(':')
        file.write(str(key))
        file.write('\n')

end_total = time.time()
```

> model.fit(train_data, validation_data=validation_data, epochs=3)

```
There is enough memory, (32G).
However, memory continues to grow.
I also replaced the memory library with libtcmalloc-minimal4.
What's the reason?
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: For what it's worth, although our pipeline was somewhat different, this happened to us as well.  We had to switch to TensorFlow Lite to solve the memory issues.

Comment: You have _500000_ images and you are caching the whole dataset. This will take over 90GB of memory.

Comment: You should remove the line ds = ds.cache() and re-run, this should avoid the OOM errors.